# Setting input value to a var through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

i'm trying to set an input value to a var named account after the user hits a button, I've tried this without jquery and everything checks out fine, but this is for an assignment and I must use jquery.

here is the html input and button:

```
<input type="" class="Re" id="Email1"/>
<button class="Re" id="Start" >Start</button>
```

Now i set the button to show an alert with the input value in the var account to check if it works, here is the code:

```
var account = "a";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Start").click(function(){
        $("#Email1").val(account);
        alert(account);
    });
});
```

account it's set on "a" mainly for testing, the "a" doesn't seem to change nothing.

Comment: This sets the input element's value to `a` correctly. Are you sure you have included the jQuery javascript file into the project?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, that's not the only jquery code on my project and all code runs as it should be, i'm trying to set whatever the user puts in the input to the var account, not the other way around.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/x40gvasL/1/ After I click the button, the input field is filled in with `a`.

Comment: If im understanding correctly, you just want `account  = $("Email1").val()`

Comment: Have you checked your [web dev console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: Tyler, thanks, but the alert says undefined to whatever i put in the input.

Comment: Yes, I've checked, is clean, no alerts.

Comment: Tyler you were right i copy/paste your code and it didn't worked cause the code read '("Email1")' instead of '("#Email1")' , thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the value of the account variable to the form field's value, call 
$.val() without arguments:

```
var account = "a";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Start").click(function(){
        account = $("#Email1").val();
        alert(account);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set account to $("#Email1").val();

```js
var account = "a";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Start").click(function() {
    account = $("#Email1").val();
    alert(account);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="" class="Re" id="Email1" />
<button class="Re" id="Start">Start</button>
```